# Finding out the highest number in a comma separated string using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, aggregate-functions

I have a table with two columns:

```
OLD_REVISIONS   |NEW_REVISIONS
-----------------------------------
1,25,26,24      |1,26,24,25
1,56,55,54      |1,55,54
1               |1
1,2             |1
1,96,95,94      |1,96,94,95
1               |1
1               |1
1               |1
1               |1
1,2             |1,2
1               |1
1               |1
1               |1
1               |1
```

- For each row there will be a list of revisions for a document (comma separated)
- The comma separated list might be the same in both columns but the order/sort might be different - e.g.

  `2,1               |1,2`

I would like to find all the instances where the highest revision in the OLD_REVISIONS column is lower than than the highest revision in NEW_REVISIONS

The following would fit that criteria

```
OLD_REVISIONS   |NEW_REVISIONS
-----------------------------------
1,2             |1
1,56,55,54      |1,55,54
```

- I tried a solution using the MINUS option (joining the table to itself) but it returns differences even for when the list is the same but in the wrong order
- I tried the function GREATEST (i.e where `greatest(new_Revisions) < greatest(old_revisions)`) but i am not sure why greatest(OLD_REVISIONS) always just returns the comma separated value. It does not return the max value. I suspect it is comparing strings because the columns are VARCHAR.

Also, `MAX` function expects a single number.

Is there another way i can achieve the above? I am looking for a pure SQL option so i can print out the results (or a PL/SQL option that can print out the results)

### Edit

Apologies for not mentioning this but for the NEW_REVISIONS i do actually have the data in a table where each revision is in a separate row:

```
"DOCNUMBER" "REVISIONNUMBER"
67          1
67          24
67          25
67          26
75          1
75          54
75          55
75          56
78          1
79          1
79          2
83          1
83          96
83          94
```

Just to give some content, a few weeks ago i suspected that there are revisions disappearing.
To investigate this, i decided to take a count of all revisions for all documents and take a snapshot to compare later to see if revisions are indeed missing.

The snapshot that i took contained the following columns:

`docnumber, count, revisions`

The revisions were stored in a comma separated list using the listagg function.

The trouble i have now is the on live table, new revisions have been added so when i compare the main table and the snapshot using a MINUS i get a difference because
of the new revisions in the main table.

Even though in the actual table the revisions are individual rows, in the snapshot table i dont have the individual rows.

I am thinking the only way to recreate the snapshot in the same format and compare them find out if maximum revision in the main table is lower than the max revision in the snapshot table (hence why im trying to find out how to find out the max in a comma separated string)

Comment: This is such the wrong way to represent these values.  You should have one row per revision, not stuff a bunch of revisions into a string.

Comment: If you properly normalize your data model, the query will be really simple

Comment: Split this table into two table (OLD and new), also you should split the coma separated values into rows. After that it would be simple.

Comment: Everything you tried failed for a very simple reason - what you have currently in the table are character strings; the fact that they are digits separated by commas is irrelevant. Any comparison you do (including with `max()` or `greatest()`) will only compare them as strings. You need to break the strings down into their component numbers.

Comment: I've edited my answer after your edit in question.

Comment: Just noticing the discrepancy between the problem and its title now. Do you need to find the highest version number (as the title says), or just the rows where the max numbers don't match?

Comment: `greatest(stringA, stringB)` will give the higher of the two strings in sort order. Whether or not the strings happen to contain commas won't make a blind bit of difference and I'm not sure why anyone would expect it to.

Answer (score 4):

Enjoy.

```
select    xmlcast(xmlquery(('max((' || OLD_REVISIONS || '))') RETURNING CONTENT) as int) as OLD_REVISIONS_max
         ,xmlcast(xmlquery(('max((' || NEW_REVISIONS || '))') RETURNING CONTENT) as int) as NEW_REVISIONS_max

from      t
;
```

Comment: @ziggy, please notice that I added **xmlcast** functions. Does it work for you on Oracle 10g?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your base table has an `id` column (versions of **what**?) - here is a solution based on splitting the rows.

**Edit**: If you like this solution, check out vkp's solution, which is better than mine. I explain why his solution is better in a Comment to his Answer.

```
with
     t ( id, old_revisions, new_revisions ) as (
       select 101, '1,25,26,24', '1,26,24,25' from dual union all
       select 102, '1,56,55,54', '1,55,54'    from dual union all
       select 103, '1'         , '1'          from dual union all
       select 104, '1,2'       , '1'          from dual union all
       select 105, '1,96,95,94', '1,96,94,95' from dual union all
       select 106, '1'         , '1'          from dual union all
       select 107, '1'         , '1'          from dual union all
       select 108, '1'         , '1'          from dual union all
       select 109, '1'         , '1'          from dual union all
       select 110, '1,2'       , '1,2'        from dual union all
       select 111, '1'         , '1'          from dual union all
       select 112, '1'         , '1'          from dual union all
       select 113, '1'         , '1'          from dual union all
       select 114, '1'         , '1'          from dual
       )
--   END of TEST DATA; the actual solution (SQL query) begins below.
select id, old_revisions, new_revisions
from (
    select id, old_revisions, new_revisions, 'old' as flag,
           to_number(regexp_substr(old_revisions, '\d+', 1, level)) as rev_no
      from t
      connect by level <= regexp_count(old_revisions, ',') + 1
         and  prior id = id
          and prior sys_guid() is not null
    union all
    select id, old_revisions, new_revisions, 'new' as flag,
           to_number(regexp_substr(new_revisions, '\d+', 1, level)) as rev_no
      from t
      connect by level <= regexp_count(new_revisions, ',') + 1
         and  prior id = id
          and prior sys_guid() is not null
     )
group by id, old_revisions, new_revisions
having max(case when flag = 'old' then rev_no end) !=
       max(case when flag = 'new' then rev_no end)
order by id           --   ORDER BY is optional
;


 ID OLD_REVISION NEW_REVISION
--- ------------ ------------
102 1,56,55,54   1,55,54   
104 1,2          1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do is to split the columns on comma separation using `regexp_substr` and checking if the max and min values are different.

[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/MFCAF25148)

```
with rownums as (select t.*,row_number() over(order by old_revisions) rn from t)
select old_revisions,new_revisions 
from rownums 
where rn in (select rn
             from rownums
             group by rn
             connect by regexp_substr(old_revisions, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null 
             or regexp_substr(new_revisions, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
             having max(cast(regexp_substr(old_revisions,'[^,]+', 1, level) as int)) 
              <> max(cast(regexp_substr(new_revisions,'[^,]+', 1, level) as int))
    )
```

Comment: Good point! The splitting is only needed in the `HAVING` clause and nowhere else. So it is best to move the splitting in the `HAVING` clause, which is evaluated only after the `GROUP BY` is evaluated. For that reason, you don't need to worry about `prior rn = rn` and avoiding cycles in the hierarchical query. Good trick to remember- hats off and +1!

Answer (score 1):

Comments say normalise data. I agree but also I understand it may be not possible. I would try something like query below:

```
select greatest(val1, val2), t1.r from (
select max(val) val1, r from (
select regexp_substr(v1,'[^,]+', 1, level) val, rowid r from tab1
  connect by regexp_substr(v1, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  ) group by r) t1
  inner join (
select max(val) val2, r from (
select regexp_substr(v2,'[^,]+', 1, level) val, rowid r from tab1
  connect by regexp_substr(v2, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  ) group by r) t2
  on (t1.r = t2.r);
```

Tested on:

```
create table tab1 (v1 varchar2(100), v2 varchar2(100));
insert into tab1 values ('1,3,5','1,4,7');
insert into tab1 values ('1,3,5','1,2,9');
insert into tab1 values ('1,3,5','1,3,5');
insert into tab1 values ('1,3,5','1,4');
```

and seems to work fine. I left rowid for reference. I guess you have some id in table.

After your edit I would change query to:

```
select greatest(val1, val2), t1.r from (
select max(val) val1, r from (
select regexp_substr(v1,'[^,]+', 1, level) val, DOCNUMBER r from tab1
  connect by regexp_substr(v1, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null
  ) group by DOCNUMBER) t1
  inner join (
select max(DOCNUMBER) val2, DOCNUMBER r from NEW_REVISIONS) t2
  on (t1.r = t2.r);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compare every value by putting together the revisions in the same order using listagg function.

```
SELECT listagg(o,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY o) old_revisions,
       listagg(n,',')  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY n) new_revisions
FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT  rowid r,
            regexp_substr(old_revisions, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) o,
            regexp_substr(new_revisions, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) n
     FROM   table
     WHERE  regexp_substr(old_revisions, '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) IS NOT NULL
     CONNECT BY LEVEL<=(SELECT greatest(MAX(regexp_count(old_revisions,',')),MAX(regexp_count(new_revisions,',')))+1 c FROM table)
     )
GROUP BY r
HAVING listagg(o,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY o)<>listagg(n,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY n);
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be a way:

```
select 
  OLD_REVISIONS,
  NEW_REVISIONS
from 
  REVISIONS t,
  table(cast(multiset(
                        select level
                        from dual
                        connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.OLD_REVISIONS, '[^,]+'))  + 1
                      ) as sys.OdciNumberList
             )
       ) levels_old,
  table(cast(multiset(
                        select level
                        from dual
                        connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.NEW_REVISIONS, '[^,]+'))  + 1
                     )as sys.OdciNumberList
            )
       ) levels_new
group by t.ROWID,
  OLD_REVISIONS,
  NEW_REVISIONS
having max(to_number(trim(regexp_substr(t.OLD_REVISIONS, '[^,]+', 1, levels_old.column_value)))) >
       max(to_number(trim(regexp_substr(t.new_REVISIONS, '[^,]+', 1, levels_new.column_value))))
```

This uses a double string split to pick the values from every field, and then simply finds the rows where the max values among the two collections match your requirement.
You should edit this by adding some unique key in the GROUP BYclause, or a rowid if you don't have any unique key on your table.

Answer (score 0):

You may write a PL/SQL function parsing the string and returning the maximal number

```
select  max_num( '1,26,24,25') max_num from dual;
   MAX_NUM
----------
        26
```

The query ist than very simple:

```
select OLD_REVISIONS  NEW_REVISIONS
from revs
where max_num(OLD_REVISIONS) < max_num(NEW_REVISIONS);
```

A prototyp function without validation and error handling

```
create or replace function max_num(str_in VARCHAR2) return NUMBER as 
i number;
x varchar2(1);
n number := 0;
max_n number := 0;
pow number := 0;
begin
 for i in 0.. length(str_in)-1 loop
  x := substr(str_in,length(str_in)-i,1);
  if x = ',' then 
    -- check max number
    if n > max_n then 
       max_n := n;
    end if;   
    -- reset
    n := 0;
    pow := 0;
  else
    n := n + to_number(x)*power(10,pow);
    pow := pow +1;
  end if;
 end loop;
 return(max_n);
end;
/
```